# Connect to database through double SSH tunnel using Python Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

Here is my `ssh` command that establish a tunnel with Postgres database by proxying through bastion host -

```sh
ssh -i C:/public/keys/my_key.pem -o "ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p username1@bastion_host.com" username2@ssh_host_ip -N -L 12345:postgres_host.com:5432 ssh_host_ip
```

I want to convert it into Python script using `sshtunnel` utility. But have hard time to figure out what to pass where in the utility as depicted:

- in example 4 over this link: https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel#example-4
- or this link: [Double SSH tunnel within Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54808935/double-ssh-tunnel-within-python)

I went through few posts on Stack Overflow but did not see a straightforward way of doing it. Developers are using agent forwarding as a solution to Proxy command. Any straightforward conversion of above command to `sshtunnel` or Paramiko or any other pythonic way would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Connecting to PostgreSQL database through SSH tunneling in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34965824/850848), the following should do:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        'bastion_host',
        ssh_username="username1", ssh_password="password1",
        remote_bind_address=('ssh_host_ip', 22)) as bastion:
        
    bastion.start()
    
    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
            ('127.0.0.1', bastion.local_bind_port),
            ssh_username="username2", ssh_pkey="C:/public/keys/my_key.pem",
            remote_bind_address=('postgres_host', 5432)) as ssh:

        ssh.start()

        engine = create_engine(
            'postgresql://<db_username>:<db_password>@127.0.0.1:' +
            str(ssh.local_bind_port) + '/database_name')
```